# Call Angular 1.5 component controller function from outside

Tags: angularjs

```
import {COLORS} from '../../constants/StylesConstants';

class SearchController {
  constructor($log, $state) {
    this.buttonRipple = COLORS.buttonRipple;
    this.showDescription = false;
    $log.log('$state.params');
    $log.log($state.params);
  }

  show(index) {
    this.showDescription = index;
  }
}


export const Search = {
  template: require('./Search.html'),
  controller: SearchController
};
```

how to call the `show` function outside this controller?
Obviously I've used routing, so there is no `ng-controller` on html.

Comment: What do you mean by "outside"? Do you mean "from the template associated to that controller"? How did you configure the router state?

Comment: No, I mean from any where in javascript file.

Comment: Then the answer is: it would make no sense.

Comment: Actually, my client is using RPC way via GWT. He's requiring me to provide JS functions so he'll be able to call.
Well it's make sense that's why we've a method for this if we've defined our controller as ng-controller.
`angular.element(document.getElementById('yourControllerElementID')).scope().<your function name>();`

Comment: So you already know what to do then. Just do that, and if the element is handled by the controller, and if the controller is in ots own scope (i.e. if you've used controllerAs), then you can call then method.

Comment: I told in the question,  **I've used routing, so there is no ng-controller on html.**

Comment: And I asked you from the beginning "How did you configure the router state?". If the controller is not even instantiated anywhere by AngularJS, you can't call it. If it is, via the router state, then whether you have ng-controler or not is irrelevant.

Comment: Yup, obviously it's instantiated in router!

Comment: Then it should be fine. And since you refuse to show how you configured it, despite me asking you several times, you should be able to figure out what to do by yourself. Bye.